# LaTeX Skak package Error: Paragraph ended before \FenBoard was complete

Tags: skak

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{skak}

\begin{document}
\mainline{1.e4}

\showboard

\lastmove{} Is the most common opening move

\mainline{1...e5 2.Nf3 Nc6 3.d4}

\showboard

\mainline{3...e5xd4 4.Bb5 a6 5.O-O}

\showboard

\end{document}
```

gives the error

"Paragraph ended before `\FenBoard` was complete"

why?

Answer (score 4):

The examples in the documentation of `skak` start with `\newgame`. Adding it before the first `\mainline` fixes the error:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{skak}

\begin{document}
\newgame % Added
\mainline{1.e4}

\showboard

\lastmove{} Is the most common opening move

\mainline{1...e5 2.Nf3 Nc6 3.d4}

\showboard

\mainline{3...e5xd4 4.Bb5 a6 5.O-O}

\showboard

\end{document}
```